# A dense subset in $L^2(X,\lambda)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose

$S=\{f\in L^2(X,\lambda): f=\alpha_1( \chi_{A_1}-\chi_{X\setminus A_1})+\sum_{i=2}^N \alpha_ i\chi_{A_i}$ where $A_i, A_j$ are disjoint and $a_1>\max_{2\leq i\leq N} \alpha_i \}$.

Is $S$ dense in $L^2(X,\lambda)$?

I can show that the class of all $f=\sum_{j=1}^J \beta_ j( \chi_{B_j}-\chi_{X\setminus B_j})$ is a dense subset.

Comment: I think  $\lambda$ can be Lebesgue measure if needed.